# How to catch http redirects programmatically?

Tags: javascript, actionscript, client-side, http-redirect

I know more specific questions asked this for ajax and that the answer is no, but I’m wanting to see a broader and newer scope.

If I’m getting redirected to a random url through a http 302 redirect which again redirects to final url, how I can get the url of the first redirect ? In my case I’m talking about cross domain get requests without cross origin permissions.
There’s no crossdomain.xml nor cors headers nor preflight request support, but I’m not needing to read full response content, but just the ᴜʀʟ, I also need to send session cookies.

For example, it it possible to do this though the newly fetch JavaScript api ? Or through Flash Player (using the [URLRequest or NetStream api](https://code.google.com/archive/p/browsersec/wikis/Part2.wiki#Same-origin_policy_for_Flash)) ?

Comment: I’m failing to understand the purpose of [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/redirect) and [this](https://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#useRedirectedURL()), and I can assign value to [this](https://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#followRedirects).

Comment: I'm not seeing a security question here. As you say, this looks more like a programming question.

Comment: @schroeder : my point is the ᴜʀʟ of first redirect is setting session cookies through Oauth so that loading it inside an other browser allows to highjack session’s victim. Please unmigrate the question.